# Lightning Components: updating data passed around application won't update on change

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I'm having trouble updating data being passed around in my application. Passing down the data to my components is easy, but updating the attribute(data) has been difficult for me.

**My Original Expectation**:

all the attribute values I'm passing down through my components are all connected to the the original workItems array inside my top-level"taskboard" component, so modifying something down the chain, I assume, should update the value at the top of the chain, but it looks like this isn't the case.

**Questions:**

- is there some aspect of immutability involved in the aura framework? For example, is the attribute data the child component have copies from the values up the chain?
- is there some re-rendering that I should be doing or refetching of data instead? I was expecting to see my UI updates after doing component.set(..) in my taskModal component.

  **User flow:**

  - I click "add Task button" on workItem component, which fires "AA_addTaskEvent" on a work item. I also package a work item object in the event.
  - The topmost component "AA_taskboard"(not .app), listens for the "addTaskEvent", adds the work item object 
    as a value to it's 'work' attrivute & invokes "handleAddTaskEvent" which unhides "AA_taskModal" component
    & passes the work item object to the modal component.
  - Inside my modal I have verified after seeing the object I recieved, that I do have access to the specific work
    item I clicked. However, when modify & update the work item, I don't see any changes happening, it's as if the item is immutable.

  Afer reading this other SO response ([link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55051/how-to-pass-values-across-lightning-components)) about passing across components, I have a hunch that it has to do with the
  values I'm passing down my components.

**AA_taskboardApp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
  <c:AA_taskboard />
</aura:application>
```

**AA_taskboard.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="AA_taskboardController">

  <aura:attribute name="workItems" type="agf__ADM_Work__c[]" description="all of the items for the current sprint. Data will in after initializing this component" />
  <aura:attribute name="work" type="agf__ADM_Work__c" description="a work item (object) that will get passed up from the 'addTaskEvent' fired from a workItem component. This work item object will later be passed to the task modal so it has access to the work item that was clicked"/>

  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" description="fetch the work item data when this component initializes" />
  <aura:handler name="addTaskEvent" event="c:AA_addTaskEvent" action="{!c.handleAddTaskEvent}" description="handles the event fired from the workItem component"/>

  <c:AA_workList workItems="{!v.workItems}" />
  <c:AA_taskModal aura:id="task-modal" work="{!v.work}" />


</aura:component>
```

**AA_taskModal.cmp**

```
<aura:component>

  <aura:attribute name="work" type="agf__ADM_Work__c" description="a work item that's passed to the modal. Flow: addNewTask event from workItem component fires and sends the work item(object) to the taskboard.cmp, then the taskboard passes it to this modal" />
  <aura:registerEvent name="saveNewTaskEvent" type="c:AA_saveNewTaskEvent" description="An event that fire after the user had entered a new task name and hit save. This event sends up the taskname to the taskboard component." />

  <div class="task-modal hide" aura:id="task-modal">
    <ui:inputText aura:id="task-input" class="slds-input" />

    <button onclick="{!c.cancelNewTask}">Cancel</button>
    <button onclick="{!c.saveNewTask}">Save</button>

  </div>

</aura:component>
```

**AA_taskModalController.js**

```
({
  saveNewTask: function(component, event, helper) {
    var taskInput = component.find('task-input');
    var newTaskName = taskInput.get("v.value"); // 'NEWTASK'

    var work = component.get("v.work");
    work.agf__Tasks__r.push({
      agf__Subject__c: newTaskName
    });
    work.agf__Subject__c = "rename work";                 
    component.set('v.work', work); //doesn't update anything. Am I updating a copy & not a reference to the work item in my taskboard.cmp's array?
  },


  //Get & hide modal  if user hits cancel on modal
  cancelNewTask: function(component, event, helper) {
    var taskModal = component.find('task-modal');
    $A.util.addClass(taskModal, "hide")
  }
})
```

**AA_workList.cmp**

```
  <aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="workItems" type="agf__ADM_Work__c[]" />

      <ol class="work-list">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.workItems}" var="workItem">
          <li class="work-item-container">
              <c:AA_workItem work="{!workItem}" tasks="{!workItem.agf__Tasks__r}"/>
          </li>
        </aura:iteration>
      </ol>

  </aura:component>
```

**AA_workItem.cmp**

```
<aura:component>

  <aura:attribute name="work" type="agf__ADM_Work__c" />
  <aura:attribute name="tasks" type="agf__ADM_Task__c[]" />  
  <aura:attribute name="showTasks" type="Boolean" default="false" />
  <aura:registerEvent name="addTaskEvent" type="c:AA_addTaskEvent" description="an application event fired when user clicks add task button on this work item. Task modal component at the root(taskboard.cmp) listens for this event." />
  <aura:handler event="c:AA_updateTaskEvent" action="{!c.updateTask}" description="Handler for application event fired from the task modal after the user had entered a new task name and hit save. This event sends up the taskname to a workItem component that's listening for it" ./>

  <div class="work-item">
    <header>{!v.work.agf__Subject__c}</header>
    <button onclick="{!c.addTask}">Add Task</button>
    <!-- Tasks -->
    <ol class="work-tasks">
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.work.agf__Tasks__r}" var="taskItem">
        <li class="task-item">
          <c:AA_taskItem task="{!taskItem}" />
        </li>
      </aura:iteration>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Just a guess, I assume it could be because you are getting current instance of the work component attribute and setting it back to work attribute, have you tried creating a new object var newwork = [] and newwork.push(work); and then set component.set('v.work', newwork );

Comment: Look similar to the issue discussed [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/147442/20830)

Comment: Doing the following inside my taskModalController updated my tasks array, but didn't change my UI to add the new task item in the list. It looks like I need to trigger an event in my modal, passing the new task item, to my taskboard & update my work items there.

`var tasks = work.agf__Tasks__r; `
`tasks.push({agf__Subject__c: newTaskName}); `
`component.set('v.work.agf__Tasks_r', tasks); `
updated my tasks array, but didn't update my list in the UI